# Recursively calling a Merge Sort algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

I'm new to recursion, and currently writing a Merge Sort algorithm that compares the first elements of two lists and determines which one is smaller, then adds the smaller one to a new list.

I'm trying to update the three lists after each comparison and have the function call itself again with the updated lists, but I'm getting unresolved reference issues in Pycharm and not sure what I'm doing wrong. Here is my code so far, my desired output is:

> new_list = [4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42, 50, 75, 108]

```
def merge_Sort(list1, list2, new_list):
    list1 = [8, 15, 16, 50, 75]
    list2 = [4, 23, 42, 108]
    new_list = []
    for i in range(len(list1)):
            if list1[0] < list2[0]:
                new_list = new_list.append(list1[0])
                list1 = list1.remove(list1[0])
                break


            elif list1[0] > list2[0]:
                new_list = new_list.append(list2[0])
                list2 = list2.remove(list2[0])
                break

    merge_Sort(list1, list2, new_list)

merge_Sort(list1, list2, new_list)
```

Comment: Not sure why the down vote. An reasonable attempt at the code is clearly shown, and the question is clearly explained.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code lead to infinite recursion. You should move `list1`,`list2` and `new_list` initialization outside of `merge_Sort` function.

```
def merge_Sort(list1, list2, new_list):
    for i in range(len(list1)):
        if list1[0] < list2[0]:
            new_list.append(list1[0])
            list1.remove(list1[0])
            break
        elif list1[0] > list2[0]:
            new_list.append(list2[0])
            list2.remove(list2[0])
            break

    merge_Sort(list1, list2, new_list)

list1 = [8, 15, 16, 50, 75]
list2 = [4, 23, 42, 108]
new_list = []
merge_Sort(list1, list2, new_list)
```

Comment: Thank you, that got it to run. Now it's telling me that 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable, and I'm receiving the error on the line of my first if statement. What could be evaluating to None here?

Comment: @Perplexityy: The `list.append` method mutates the list; it's a Python convention that such methods do **not** return a reference to the mutated object, they return `None`. Similar remarks apply to `.remove`, So your code (and kvorobiev's version) clobbers your various lists, replacing them with `None`.